# uibarbuttonitem not working

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Refresh" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(refreshButtonClicked:)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:refreshButton animated:YES];
}
- (void)refreshButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Refreshed.");
}
```

I added a navigation controller programmatically in AppDelegate and set this view as the root.

When I was trying to add a navigationItem programmatically as shown above, the `refreshButton` showed in the navigation bar but `refreshButtonClicked:` was not invoked.

What's the problem? Any suggestions and comments are welcome.

Comment: How you detect that `refreshButtonClicked:` was not invoked? This code is worked.

Comment: @beryllium `NSLog(@"Refreshed.");` have no output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Weird. After I clean the builds, delete the derived data and restart Xcode, it goes runs properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make a call to the super class in your viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Refresh" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(refreshButtonClicked:)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:refreshButton animated:YES];
}
```

It will ensure that the root class setup is done